# object of class cannot be converted to string

Tags: php, html, oop, object

I know this is an old question but I am not finding answer. Here is my code:

```
class SqlConnect implements connectionInterface {
//put your code here
private $datasource=null;
private $credentials = null;

public function __construct() {
    $netsConn = new configInit(); // Here where the error is happing
    $datasource = $this->$netsConn->getDatabase();
    $credentials = $this->$netsConn->getBasicCredentials();
}
public function connect() 
{
    $conn = mysqli_connect($datasource['servername'], $credentials['username'], $credentials['password']);
    if (!$conn)
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } else {
    return $conn;
    }
}


}
```

I am then calling the class like

```
class applicationsController implements Controller {

private $conn = null;

 public function __construct() {
     $conn = new SqlConnect();
    $this->$conn->connect();
 }
...
}
```

However I am getting the following error:

> > Catchable fatal error: Object of class configInit could not be converted to string

This error happens in SqlConnect. I have looked through about 6 answers on stackoverflow and most all of them were about trying to echo some objects, which is not my case

Comment: Well, I observe that variable `$arnetsConn` is neither declared *private,* nor is it *used.* Where *is* `configInit` declared? ## Also, why are you not saying things like `$this->credentials`?

Comment: what is configInit? and if class where this loaded?

Comment: What is the configInit class even used for? Have you tried simply stepping through your code?

Comment: comment out that line and run without it. If you showed us all that matter, that line is irrelevant.

Comment: @MikeRobinson it is an editing mistake.. I just edited.. the error is before the assignment to $credentials

Comment: @georaldc configInit is the class that does datasource configuration and connection initializations

Comment: @AmirKhan configInit is the class that does datasource configuration and connection initializations

Comment: @BeetleJuice I just edited the code.. there was an editing mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, I think I see it.

You are assigning to *global variable* `$netsConn`, not *object property* `$netsConn` ...

Try this:

```
 private $netsConn;
 ...
 $this->netsConn = new configInit();
```

... that is, if you want to keep it around.  Otherwise, refer directly to the variable not to a *(never-declared ...)* property.

Comment: I have tried it but the problem with this is that when I call the SqlConnect in the applicationsController.. I get undefined variable $netsConn. which is a bit supprising

Comment: It shouldn't be!  Notice how you are assigning the new class instance to a *global variable,* **not** to a property of your object!  Then, you refer to "a property of your object" to get the value.  (Although you never declare that property.) There will be no value there to retrieve.  Look **very carefully(!)** at the first three lines of `_construct`, and be prepared to whack yourself on the forehead and say, *"d'oh!"*  How ... is ... the ... first ... ... line ... different ... from ... the .. second ... and ... third?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get the error is because of the following 2 lines

```
netsConn = new configInit(); // Here where the error is happing
$datasource = $this->$netsConn->getDatabase();
```

First line is fine, but on the second line, you are using $netsConn as an attribute name for the SqlConnect class ($this). For this to work, php has to use the string representation of $netsConn by attempting to call it's implementation of the magic method __toString(). Since this probably does not exist in your configInit() class, you end up with that error.

Comment: Take note that Mike's answer should point you to the right direction. His suggestion of turning $netsConn into a member of your SqlConnect class is what you are actually trying to do.